# Abrir uma nova janela "dentro" da janela atual

Tags: javascript, html, css

possuo uma página onde eu insiro alguns dados e clico em submit, é feita uma consulta no banco e me retorna um .xml em outra janela.
Pois bem, eu gostaria de saber se é possível, colocar um campo na janela atual, para que este retorno em .xml apareça nele?
Atualmente está como na foto anexa.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teria que usar AJAX, mas tem que ver se a página requisitada aceita CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o jquery para isso para que sua resposta seja colocada dentro de alguma div por exemplo

HTML:

```
<div id='conteudo'> </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#centeudo').append(<div>SEU CONTEUDO CAPTURADO DO HTML AQUI</div>);
```